# Why does every restart of hive-server needs restart of hue

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hue

As per hue documentation:

> Hue is an open source Web interface for analyzing data with any Apache Hadoop

So, hue acts as a client to hive-server. 
Why restart of hive-server is not transparent to hue?

When I restart my hive-server [due to some changes in hive-site.xml] I get following error on hue

```
: Max retries exceeded with url: /cliservice/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f77d07f12d0>
: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

When I restart hue service. Things are back to normal.

Why does every restart of hive-server needs restart of hue?

Comment: What is your Hive configuration? Seems like it is using HA via Zookeeper or Tez/LLAP, which does not support retstarts yet out of the box in Hue yet.

Comment: Yes. We use TEZ/LLAP. Thanks for the update that it is not yet supported. I am curious to know what is happening behind the scene. Since, your are part of hue team may be you can add some details in the answer about how (connection between hue and hive-server) works.

Comment: It is only because the exception name is not matched by the session expiration regexp. https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-9100 should fix it, in the meantime, login ou of Hue or closing the session via the Editor session menu should recreate the session.